# How to allow two results when searching

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a dictionary/translator but I want to let the user write, 'hello' and 'Hello' and still receive the result 'Ronne'.

```
print ("English to Exrian Dictionary")
search = input("Enter the word you would like to translate: ")

if search == "Hello":
    print ("Ronne")
elif search == "Bye":
    print ("Zio")
else:
    print ("No matches were found for '" + search + "'")
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, in addition to the `.lower()` approach, you could also do something like `if search in ['Hello','hello']:` -- in this case, it seems less-clear approach than using `.lower()`, but it is still an option to be aware of.

Comment: Using `if...elif...` is ok for a couple of words, but if you want to handle a larger number of words you should use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 1):

To ignore the case, just convert your search to lowercase

```
search = search.lower()
if search == "hello":
    print ("Ronne")
```

Comment: i want it to allow the user to write "Hello" or "hello" to get the same answer.

Comment: @MichaelThin that's exactly what this will do. Just try it.

Comment: but i want the users input. like this. search = input("example:").lower()

Comment: i tried that it dont work. do i need to add input part?

Comment: Well, yes this code comes after the line `search = input(...)`. If you use `search = input(...).lower()`, you already converted it to lowercase, no need to do it again.

Answer (score 0):

You could just convert your input to lowercase, and compare to "hello", like this:

```
search = input("Enter the word you would like to translate: ").lower()

if search == "hello":
    print("Ronne")
```